# What is wrong with my program to find the longest word in a sentence?

Tags: c++, algorithm

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[101]{0};
    cin>>a;
    cin.getline(a,101);
    cin.ignore();

    int currLen{0};
    int maxLen{0};
    int startInd{-1};
    int endInd{-1};

    for(int i=0; i<101; i++) {
        if(a[i]!=' ' ) {
            ++currLen;
        } else if(a[i]==' '||a[i]=='\0') {
            if(currLen>maxLen) {
                maxLen=currLen;
                startInd=i-currLen;
                endInd=i-1;
            }

            if(a[i]=='\0')
                break;
            currLen=0;
        }
    }

    cout<<maxLen<<endl;
    if(startInd==-1)
        cout<<-1;
    else
        for(int i=startInd; i<=endInd; i++)
            cout<<a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

If I take an input here, for example, "My name is Manav Kampani"
It will output **5
Manav** instead of **7
Kampani**
But if I write "My name is Manav Kampani ", with space after the last word
than it is considering ***Kampani*** too printing **Kampani**.

Also when I input "Kampani Manav is my name" then too it's displaying the wrong output. That means it is not considering the first word of the sentence.

Comment: is there a reason your are not using `std::string` or anything from the standard library?

Comment: Take a small failing input and start debugging.

Comment: You have the best clue in your own question:  "_if I write ... with space after_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice **sliding window** pattern implementation.

You have 3 problems in your code

1. You must not write `cin >> a;`
2. You must not write `cin.ignore();`
3. You need to modify your `if` statement like so: `if (a[i] != ' ' && a[i] != '\0')` Otherwise you will not detect the last word.

Your complete working code with that minor fixes will lokk like that.

```
int main()
{
    char a[101]{ 0 };
    //cin >> a;
    cin.getline(a, 101);
    //cin.ignore();

    int currLen{ 0 };
    int maxLen{ 0 };
    int startInd{ -1 };
    int endInd{ -1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] != ' ' && a[i] != '\0')// Add comparison
        {
            ++currLen;
        }
        else if (a[i] == ' ' || a[i] == '\0')
        {
            if (currLen > maxLen)
            {
                maxLen = currLen;
                startInd = i - currLen;
                endInd = i - 1;
            }
            if (a[i] == '\0')
                break;
            currLen = 0;
        }
    }
    cout << maxLen << endl;

    if (startInd == -1)
        cout << -1;
    else
        for (int i = startInd; i <= endInd; i++)
            cout << a[i];
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally. You should not use C-Style arrays in C++. And please use `std::string`

Comment: Thanks for such a nice explanation. Please also tell when to use the cin.ignore() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(a[i]!=' ' )
  {
      ++currLen;
  }
  
  else if(a[i]==' '||a[i]=='\0')
  {
  ....
  }
```

Consider the case of a[i] == 0. Which of these if-statements will apply.

Answer: the first one. Which means you'll never look at the final word in the string. You also don't exit at the end of the string, but instead loop through whatever is in your string all the way out to character 101.

As a general structure, be very, very careful with this:

```
if (condition)
else if (condition)
// without a final else section
```

If you do that, you need to think about what you're doing. In this particular case, you can have:

```
if (a[i] != 0 && a[i] != ' ')
else
```

It may not solve all your issues, but it should solve some.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of things here:

1- You don't need to do a `cin>>a` this is actually consuming the first word, and afterwards the content is overrided by `cin.getline().` So removing the firsst `cin>>a`you'll be fine.

2- The last word is not read because there isn't any if condition that matches the condition aka.

```
     if(a[i]!=' ' ) case of not a space
      //not end of word
      else if(a[i]==' '||a[i]=='\0') case of space or null
      //end of word
```

So your last character is not a space nor null, that means you don't detect the last word.